# Don't know how to add title_suffix

Tags: nodes

I am working on existing Drupal project. I am begineer at Drupal and I need a help with something. In one node I've got title with title_suffix. This node is a view. I want to edit this title_suffix, but I don't know how and where to look at it. Could anyone help me please? Where do I have to looking for? UI or template files or where? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a preprocess function to populate `$title_suffix`. It belongs in a file called template.php in your theme folder.

Here's a primer: [Setting up variables for use in a template](https://www.drupal.org/node/223430).

A basic example that populates the variable `$foo` and makes it available to page.tpl.php (Drupal 7.x):

```
<?php
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['foo'] = 'bar';      
}
?>
```

The core module **Contextual links** populates `$title_suffix` in its implementation of hook_preprocess(). View source at [modules/contextual/contextual.module](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21contextual%21contextual.module/7) for an example of how it is done.